# Avoid numerous casts in inheritance tree

Tags: c#, inheritance, casting

This is a problem which seems super basic but I still can't find a way to clear it. When I have a simple inheritance like B and C inheriting from A

```
   A
   |
|-----|
B     C
```

Let's say these are interface like:

```
public interface A
{
    List<A> Children { get; }
}
```

**My issue:** When I got through `B.Children` I have to cast it to `B` every time I want to use its specifics. Is there a way to have a list of children without having to declare the children in the leaves of the inheritance tree?

Precision: A child is always of the same type as its parent (or sub-type). And the tree can go deeper. As an example, think about a UI system with objects, containers, controls, labels where a class has as children only things of the same type or sub-types of itself.

---

Here is my code. I have the top level as

```
public interface ITerm
{
    String text { get; }
}
```

Then, as offered by @Damien_The_Unbeliever

```
public interface ITerm<T> : ITerm where T : ITerm
{
    List<T> Children { get; }
}

public interface ITermControl : ITerm<ITermControl> { ... }

public class TermControl : ITermControl { ... }
```

I am starting to think it is useless to have access to a `List<ITerm> ITerm.Children` as well as `List<ITermControl> ITermControl.Children`. That's what I was trying to explain.

Thanks

Comment: Does a type always have the same type as itself as children? Does your inheritance hierarchy actually go deeper? I think we're going to need more context here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might try doing this:

```
public interface A<T> where T: A<T> {
    List<T> Children {get;}
}
```

Which Eric Lippert describes in his article [Curiouser and Curiouser](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser.aspx):

> This is a C# variation on what's called the [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) in C++, and I will leave it to my betters to explain its uses in that language. Essentially the pattern in C# is an attempt to *enforce* the usage of the CRTP.

And points out that it doesn't really *enforce* correct types throughout - so at best, it's a form of documentation rather than something that prevents bad things from happening.

Comment: I thought about that but then we cannot really use the parent interface and the inheritance is losing a bit of interest.

Comment: @Mr.Pe - well, we might do better if you can remove some of the abstraction from your question and present the concrete use case(s) we have to meet.

Comment: @Mr.Pe if you use interface it means your base class will be abstract nothing get lost. If you desire using base attributes you should use a class instead.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I can't reach your type writing :) I think you have additional fingers :)

Comment: @Mr.Pe - you might also want to consider (if there are more members of `A` than you've shown), splitting it into two interfaces - `A` and `A<T>`, with those members that don't depend on the derived type being placed in `A`. At the end of the day though, in order to meet your "no casting" requirement, the `Children` method has to return a type known at compile time to be a derived type, and so there should never be an issue with selecting the correct `T`.

Comment: I think @Damien_The_Unbeliever is right I'm deleting my answer. +1

Comment: Uuh the double interface system sounds very interesting!